# How to tie Send/Open/Click Events to Campaign via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

We have an external CRM system. We are trying to pull in campaigns and open & click events and correlate them. I'm able to retrieve [Open events](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/openevent/) and [Click events](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/clickevent/) via the SOAP API and can retrieve Campaigns via the REST API. But is it possible to tie the open and click events to a specific campaign? I can't quite figure out the link between them.

Comment: Phil, can you please add more details to your question.. are you doing this outside salesforce ? what are you referring by click events ? are you trying to link events to campaigns from an external system ?

Comment: Vamsi, this is ExactTarget speak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil,

You'll have to use a combination of the REST APIs and SOAP API.

You'll get the campaign and campaign assets back using these two REST routes:

- [One Campaign](http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/campaigns/getCampaign.html)
- [Campaign Assets](http://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/campaigns/getCampaignAssetCollection.html)

After you get the campaign assets back, you'll then want to use the send summary in the SOAP API to get back a batch of SendIDs filtered (probably a SimpleFilterPart) by the ObjectIDs that the REST route gave you.

After that, you can use the SendIDs for each send to get back the opens and clicks via SOAP.

Hope this helps!