# How to send authenticated REST request with Python

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest, fuel-sdk, python

Complete noobie question here. I'm trying to access the REST API for `ExactTarget` to access `Campaign` data and open / clicks etc using Python

I have installed the `FuelSDK` and can perform requests such as those found on GIT [here](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/objsamples/sample_sentevent.py).

[This post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57834/how-to-tie-send-open-click-events-to-campaign-via-api) references the REST/SOAP api to connect campaigns with clickers.

Can anyone tell me how to access the REST urls in Python?

Comment: check [Getting an Access Token](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/using-the-api-key-to-authenticate-api-calls.html) and [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120318/accessing-the-salesforce-api-for-the-first-time-using-python/120323#120323)

Comment: Sorry for the basic question. But How to i authenticate.  r=requests.post('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns', 'Content-Type: application/json{"clientId": "XXXXX","clientSecret": "XXXX"}')
returns 401 error. so i know the url is good, but i cannot authenticate ?

Answer (score 2):

Please read exacttarget [api reference](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/using-the-api-key-to-authenticate-api-calls.html)

You couldn't access resources without authorization. First you should request for an Access Token:

```
import json, requests

client_Id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FROM_APP_CENTER"
client_Secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_APP_CENTER"

payload = {
    'clientId': client_Id,
    'clientSecret': client_Secret
}

url = "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken";

r = requests.post(url,
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    data=payload)

body = json.loads(r.content)
token = body["accessToken"]
expiresIn = body["expiresIn"]
print token
```

Now you can access your resources using Access Token:

```
url="https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns?$page=1&$pageSize=2&$orderBy=Name ASC"

r = requests.get(url, headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + token})
print r.content
```

Before using Python, I recommend you to try [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), it will help you to understand requests etc.

Comment: I dont have access to exacttarget , please add here errors if you have any

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. If you absolutely want to use python, there are several libraries that can help you achieve this. two of them are simple-salesforce and Beatbox.

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beatbox/32.1
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce
```

here is an example using beatbox:

```
import beatbox

"salesforceusername and password"
username = 'yourUsername'
password = "yourPassword"
token    = 'yourToken'

svc = beatbox.PythonClient()
svc.login(username, password+token)

"""Simple SOQL query that returns all cases"""
res = svc.query("SELECT id FROM case")


print(res)
```

you can equally use this library to create/uptade or simply access Sobjects.

If you decide to use python, be carefull with the version you are using. I did the above using python2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simple-salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce)
`pip install simple-salesforce`

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

email = user@gmail.com
password = 'your_password'
security_token = 'admlnlkrsl'

sf = Salesforce(username=email, password=password, security_token=security_token)
```

**Where to find `security token`?**

In SalesForce, using `Lightning` Theme:

1. Click in the top right corner your `profile icon` -> `Settings`;
2. In the tree select `My Personal Information` -> `Reset My Security Token`;
3. Click `Reset Security Token`;
4. Check your email for a new token.